# Expo web browser emulator is blank - React Native Error

Tags: react-native, web, expo, emulation, react-native-navigation

While working on my app yesterday, the web emulator of Expo was working properly.

Now when I am trying to start the app on the browser today using `expo start` and then `w`, the whole screen is blank.

Nothing is there on the browser.

What kind of issue is this? How should I fix this?

Image of the emulator:

[image]

****EDIT****

These are the Screenshot from Snack:

App.js

[image]

LoginScreen.js

[image]

HomeScreen.js

[image]

Comment: does it work on snack??

Comment: This is the error I am getting on snack 
`package.json (3:5)
Failed to resolve dependency 'firebase@9.6.2' (Can't resolve '' in '/tmp/snackager/snackager/buildStatus/1/firebase@9.6.2-ios,android,web/package'`

Though the Firebase version on my device is `8.2.3` and on snack it downloaded `9.6.2` on it's own.

Is that the issue I need to fix?

Comment: @chikabala 
I fixed the version on snack, now it's showing this error 

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
(Device)`

Comment: please consider adding the code so we can have a look at it

Comment: Yes, I have edited in the screenshots from snack.

Comment: Could I ask how you're getting previews in the right side of your window? Is it some extension?

Comment: Its snack, online emulator for react-native.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is in navigation and has nothing to do with emulator,

the issue is that react Navigation on web require linking prop, you can check for details in [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links)

Another solution is to use `@react-navigation/web` and here is a example [web navigation in react native](https://codersera.com/blog/how-to-do-navigation-in-react-native-web-in-2020/)

For your case try using :

```
const LoginScreen({navigation})
```

and use navigation object normally like that :

```
navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
```

no need to use `useNavigation`

Comment: What if I use snack? Do I have to change from "useNavigation" to "useRef", for navigation?

Comment: @GouravSanyal check my update

Comment: So I should work with 'navigation ref' while applying your suggested method?

Comment: no don't import anything in your navigation screens, just call `{navigation}` as a prop and use it easy as that

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the input. Let me get back if something else breaks.